# Django i18n_patterns without trailing slash

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I'm trying to get rid of trailing slash from urls. Currently the web-server successfully removes slashes and `APPEND_SLASH = false` Everything works fine but I have a problem with the localized homepage:

```
http://example.com/en/ - ok
http://example.com/en - Page not found (404)

Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^en/

The current URL, en, didn't match any of these.
```

This is my urls.py settings:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

It it possible to make these i18n_patterns work without slashes?

Comment: The ending slash is [hardcoded](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3eb679a86956d9eedf24492f0002de002f7180f5/django/urls/resolvers.py#L514), You could create your own subclass, just be aware that it's a private API.

Comment: Add the slash and remove `APPEND_SLASH ` from settings. It's a bad taste to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a middleware that does the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils import translation

def add_i18npatterns_trailing_slash(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        response = get_response(request)
        if response.status_code == 404:
            language_code = translation.get_language()
            if request.path.endswith(language_code):
                return redirect(f'{request.path}/')
        return response
    return middleware
```